# Ionic In-App Update plugin not working after build

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, ionic5

I have an ionic 5 app with plugin @ionic-native/in-app update,this plugin works when running from the android studio via usb device. but the same plugin seems to get stuck after checking for update the the built apk is run on same device. can anybody help we with this please?

I tried debugging from the android studio and the process goes fine when usb debugging but not when built apk is run on device.